# How should I show this space is contractible?

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $X \neq \emptyset $ then show that $Y = (X\times [0,1]) / (X \times \{1\})$ is contractible.

Any hints?

Comment: This is false. Your space is $X\times [0,1)$, that deformation retracts onto $X$, so it is contractible if and only if $X$ is.

Comment: Do you mean to take the **quotient** of $X\times [0,1]$ by $X\times 1$? Then the notation is $(X\times [0,1]){\color{red} /}(X\times 1)$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff . You are right , I missed the notation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One picture you can have is that you have $X$ as some strange kind of $x$-axis, and then you have the interval on the $y$-axis. In essence you thicken $X$ a bit by taking the product with the interval.

Then you have the quotient part: you identify every point in the end of the interval, kind of like the tip of an umbrella. If you now retract the entire space up to the tip of the umbrella, you're left with only the tip. Draw a picture!

When you're done thinking about it and want to write something down explicitly, you will probably arrive at something similar to Tsemo's answer. But I think the fun part is to see it for yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f_t:Y=X\times [0,1]/(X\times \{1\})\rightarrow X\times [0,1]/(X\times \{1\})$ $t\in [0,1]$ defined by $f_t([x,u])=([x,u+(1-u)t]$, where $[x,u]$ is the image of $(x,u)$ by the quotient map $X\times [0,1]\rightarrow X\times [0,1]/(X\times \{1\})$. It is a retract from $Y$ to $[x,1]$ which does not depend of $x$.